# How to write .htaccess for my website directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

how to write .htaccess file for my website directory.

i dont get any errors when i run it locally on my PC.

but when i open it live on browser, it shows an error.

My website directory :-

please help.

This is aa glimpse of the error.log file

Comment: Make sure you have enable `Mod_rewrite` module on your server. you can check by `phpinfo()`

Comment: if its not enabled ...how to enable iit

Comment: its depend on which server you are working on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2

Comment: i enabled it .... but still the error persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that in your local Apache installation the .htaccess works fine while when you upload the files to another server it stops working, is that correct? In this case you might want to check the remote server's error_log, in which you can find the detailed error, it might be you are using some directives you are not allowed to (see "AllowOverride" in apache docs)

Comment: Yes you don't have mod rewrite loaded in your apache2, install it and restart your apache2 daemon then if the error persists check again error_log for a new different message and post it